# How to write these conditions correctly so that they work in the console?

Tags: c++

friends. I have a big request for you. You must complete this task, but I cannot figure out how to complete it. I can’t even understand where to start here((( Write the code, please = (

==========================================================================

A character is entered from the keyboard whose value is 'o', 'n' ... 'd' - the first letters of the names of the months. Depending on the character entered, the program should output in accordance with October, November, ..., December. For months starting with the same letter, follow these steps: if the character 'm' is entered, then the message “March or May” is displayed, if the character “j” is entered, the message “June or July” is displayed. If the sign does not match the name of a single month, nothing is displayed.

All tasks are performed in the console. I will be very grateful for the decision !!

Comment: You are directly asking the question from the community. Haven't even started writing a single line of code.

Comment: I do not know where to start (
There is an idea to iterate over all the first letters of the months through the If loop, but I don't like it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should probably try to write some code before asking for help though!

For reading in a value from the console you should use `std::cin`. A bit of guidance, you could take a look at the STL `std::map` class to help you prepare a mapping.

Alternatively you could just use a long list of `if` statements or a `switch` statement for cleaner code!

Example

```
if (c == 'o') std::cout << "October" << std::endl;
else if (c == 'n') ...
```

or

```
switch(c) {
    case 'o':
        std::cout << "October" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'n':
    ...
}
```

Hope this sets you on the right direction!